# Calculating Midprice in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with intraday time and quote data in pandas, and struggling to find a good way to calulate a weighted mid-price. I currently have the data represented as four dataframes (bid_price, bid_quantity, ask_price, ask_quantity), with the columns of each dataframe being individual instruments, and the index being timestamps. (So a single bid price could be referenced as:

```
bid_price['AAPL'][datetime(2013,1,1,9,30,0,0)]
```

The midpoint formula that I wish to apply is dependent on the bid/ask spread of the instrument. If the current spread is wider than the minimum tick increment, the midpoint will be the simple average of bid and ask prices at that moment. If the spread is equal to the minimum, the midpoint is weighted based on the bid and ask quantity.

Here is the current code:

```
def get_midprice(bid_price, bid_quantity, ask_price, ask_quantity, tick_increment=0.01):
    if (ask_price - bid_price) > tick_increment:
        return (ask_price + bid_price) / 2
    else:
        return ((bid_price * ask_quantity) + (ask_price * bid_quantity)) / (bid_quantity + ask_quantity)
```

This works on a single datapoint, and on a previous version of pandas, it also worked when passed 4 DataFrames. Now, 4 dataframes raises an exception:

```
raise ValueError("Cannot call bool() on DataFrame.")
ValueError: Cannot call bool() on DataFrame.
```

Which I believe is due to this change: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/1073

The problem could obviously solved by looping, but on a large dataset, this is very slow. Is there a better way?

Comment: Tried `if all((askP - bidP) > tick_increment):` which throws `raise Exception('Must have 0<= axis <= 1')
Exception: Must have 0<= axis <= 1` and when I specify an axis, it throws `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: How about: `(askP - bidP) > tick_increment).all().all()` ?

Comment: I'm not sure this used to work.  If I'm reading the code right, the intent is to apply this function to corresponding elements of the four `DataFrames`.  But that's not what it did in olden times-- previously, I'm pretty sure the first branch would have been taken, because `(ask_price - bid_price) > tick_increment` was non-empty, and thus truthlike.  So I suspect this code was buggy in the past.  We can write a vectorized version of this which can work, at the cost of doing twice the work, but if there's a multi-DataFrame version of `applymap` I'm not sure I've used it.

Comment: `(askP - bidP) > tick_increment).all().all()` runs without errors, but appears to always return false, as the resulting midpoint data all seems to be weighted, even if the difference between the bid_price and ask_price is greater than the tick_increment - so `return (ask_price + bid_price) / 2` never runs.

Comment: @DSM it definitely ran without errors, though I'm not certain it was getting the right result. I may try installing an older version to find out what was actually getting calculated. I think you are understanding what I am aiming to do - essentially apply the midpoint formula for each symbol, and at each timestamp, in the same way that I could get a DataFrame of bid/ask spreads using `spread = ap - bp`.

Comment: I didn't say it would have given an error, only that it wouldn't have worked. :^)  It would have given you the wrong answer, because the first branch would always have been taken.  Basically, you can't vectorize an `if` branch-- it'll always either be taken or not.  So either you have to use something which operates on elements (so you can `if` appropriately) or use an algebraic workaround.

Comment: That makes sense. I'd already looked through the documentation, and apply() looked like it might be the way to go, but I couldn't figure out how to get it to work in this case, i.e. using a function that takes multiple frames (or even multiple columns) as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

As I tried to convey in the comments, you can't vectorize an `if` branch the way you're trying, and so while the code wouldn't have raised an exception in the past, it almost certainly wasn't doing what you want it to.  That's why `array`s (and now `DataFrame`s) error out instead when `bool()` is called, to help avoid this bug.

One way around this would be an an apply-elementwise function which built a new `DataFrame` from applying a function on (effectively) zipped corresponding elements.  There may be one, although I haven't used it.   (I'd support adding one.  It's handy sometimes, and in our homegrown n-dimensional C# library I have an apply-to-matched-elements function.)

Usually when I need to do something like this pre-pandas, I just computed both branches and then combined the result (taking advantage of the fact that False ~ 0 and True ~ 1):

```
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> a > 3
array([False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> w = a > 3
>>> (a**2) * w + (1000) * (1-w)
array([1000, 1000, 1000, 1000,   16,   25,   36,   49,   64,   81])
```

but in both `numpy` and `pandas` we can also use `where`, so one version of your code would be:

```
def get_midprice(bp, bq, ap, aq, ti):

    above = (ap + bp)/2
    not_above = ((bp*aq) + (ap*bq))/(bq+aq)
    use_above = (ap - bp) > ti

    combined = not_above.where(use_above, above)

    return combined
```

The downside of this approach is that you have to compute both branches, and it uses a bit more memory.  In practice it seldom causes me problems, but YMMV.  Note that one minor advantage of using multiplication (even though it's a little slower) instead of `where` is that it'll work when being passed scalars too.

Finally, you could also consider changing your format to keep the information together, possibly using a hierarchical multi-index, but I don't have much experience there.

Comment: Thanks, but did you mean `combined = above.where(use_above, not_above)`? That change seems to work.